# automatically minimize the access levels in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a tool to go through a C# solution and minimize all the access levels?  E.g. if a class was `public` and it nothing outside the assembly was using it, it would be made `internal`.  If a class had an `internal` or `public` member that was never used outside the class hierarchy it would be made `protected`, etc.

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible with only the tool-set provided with Visual Studio. You should look at 3rd party tools out there

Comment: I am asking about 3rd party tools

Comment: Resharper might support this, but I've honestly never looked for it.  Interesting question, though.

Comment: This could work to some extent for an app, but not for a library dll. The decision of making language elements public is an explicit one, enabling potentially unknown consumers to access that element...

Answer (score 4):

Resharper (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper) will often suggest modifications like this to you, however it will not do it automatically for you.  It also has solution analysis that will identify these errors or warnings across the entire solution so you can go find them and decide if you want to fix them or not.

I've never seen a tool that would just iterate over your code and make these changes automatically (I'm not really sure why you would want to do that).

Comment: Because some developers have not been careful in doing this on their own.  They know if they make it "public" it will definitely work so that's what they do.

Comment: @JoelFan I guess I can see that, but it just seems dangerous to have a tool that would do this automatically.  I like the idea of this being a suggestion and allow you to choose if you want to take that suggestion.  I guess it's a personal preference thing.  But also, if you're talking about DLL's, how would you account for external references?

Comment: It would be specifically for a self-contained app.  Also I wouldn't mind having to make a decision on each one.

Comment: @JoelFan n that case just make everything private and you can go through an increase the availability until things compile ;) .  Note that if your underlying problem is developers making things public when they shouldn't be there's a good chance they're using that higher accessibility and so the tool couldn't catch it; it's a more fundamental problem of bad developers that isn't so easily fixed.